# Spring4 + JUnit: No qualifying bean of type [dao.impl.GenericDAOImpl] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 33

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, generics, junit

I'm creating an app with Spring 4 & Hibernate.
When I run the app in the server, it works fine. However, when I run the unit test, the console shows the following error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [dao.impl.GenericDAOImpl] is defined:
>   expected single matching bean but found 33:
>   genericDAO,userDAO,profileDAO,chartDAO,dashboardDAO,
>   ...

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:beans.xml"})

public class UserServiceTest extends BaseTest {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.out.println("Before");
    userService = new UserServiceImpl();
}

@Test
public void testAdd () {
    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail("email");
    user.setFirstName("firstName");
    user.setLastName("lastName");
    user.setPassword("password");
    userService.create(user);
}

public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you shouldn't be creating a new UserService in an integration test like this. If your beans.xml is properly constructed the UserService should be injected. If you create a new object in your `@Before` method then you are not doing an integration test as its not spring-managed and none of the bean dependencies within will be resolved.

Secondly, Spring can see see 33 different implementations of the GenericDAO interface. Is this UserService a class you created yourself? If it is, you should use a qualifier when you are defining your userDAO within your userService. i.e.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDAO")
```

Comment: I already tried to put `@Qualifier` in the service class but still doesn't work. However, it works fine in the main app with or without `@Qualifier`. As I know Spring4 doesn't need `@Qualifier` anymore. This is my service class: 

`public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {`
`@Autowired`
`@Qualifier("userDAO")`
`private UserDAO userDAO;`
`@Autowired`
`@Qualifier("profileDAO")`
`private ProfileDAO profileDAO;`
`...`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

It's a JDK & JRE issue. I used JDK 6, after I changed to JDK 7, it works fine.